# Recent update to Ubuntu 22.04.1 desktop disabling RTL 8812 BU dongle

Tags: updates

The recent update to Ubuntu 22.04.1 desktop disabled my wifi dongle which uses RTL 8812 BU. I restored a full backup so I am back up and running now (without the update).  Is there anything I can do to avoid this problem apart from not loading the update?

```
dkms status
rtl88x2bu/5.3.1: added
rtl88x2bu/5.6.1: added
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-58-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-60-generic, x86_64: installed
```

This is the state before the update.
I will reload the update and report the revised status - this may take a while.

The update is to 22.04.2 LTS.
The DKMS Status after the update is:

```
dkms status
rtl88x2bu/5.3.1: added
rtl88x2bu/5.6.1: added
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-58-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/git, 5.15.0-60-generic, x86_64: installed
```

(i.e. Unaltered).

I tried Answer 1 but this is what I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
dkms is already the newest version (2.8.7-2ubuntu2.1).
git is already the newest version (1:2.34.1-1ubuntu1.8).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 7 not to upgrade.
fatal: destination path 'RTL8812BU' already exists and is not an empty directory.
Error! The module/version combo: rtl88x2bu-5.3.1 is not located in the DKMS tree.
Deleting module rtl88x2bu-5.6.1 completely from the DKMS tree.
Error! The module/version combo: rtl88x2bu-git is not located in the DKMS tree.
Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.6.1/source -> /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1
Error! Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.13.1 does not exist.
```

Comment: Please add output of `dkms status` to your question.

Comment: You haven't provided clues as to the upgraded packages (*which can vary depending on how often you perform upgrades; daily; weekly; etc as the upgraded packages you have accrued can vary*) but if the upgrade shifted you from 22.04.1 to 22.04.2 (*which an upgraded system will report as now*) and were using the HWE kernel stack (*default for Ubuntu Desktop installs*) the kernel changes from 5.15 to 5.19.  One *fix* is to use the GA kernel stack meaning you'll remain on the 5.15 kernel for the life of the product (*as Server systems, and many flavor installs default to*); an option maybe.

Comment: @guiverc It is quote clear what has happened. The 5.19 kernel installed and an old driver didn't build. I need an answer from OP on what is installed. I know what should work then.

Comment: You had already this directory `RTL8812BU`, that was the problem. Delete it and start with `git clone` again. Also check what is in your `dkms status` now and remove that.

Comment: Better have a look to the BrosTrend site: https://linux.brostrend.com

Answer (score 1):

Recently Ubuntu 22.04 got a HWE kernel update to major version 5.19.

Some of 3rd-party drivers don't build with this kernel.

You can install new drivers for this device that will build with this kernel. But you need to remove old ones.

Run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install git dkms
rm -r RTL8812BU
git clone -b v5.13.1 https://github.com/fastoe/RTL8812BU.git
sudo dkms remove rtl88x2bu/5.3.1 --all
sudo dkms remove rtl88x2bu/5.6.1 --all
sudo dkms remove rtl88x2bu/git --all
sudo dkms add RTL8812BU
sudo dkms install rtl88x2bu/5.13.1
```

If all comes without errors, you can upgrade you system to kernel 5.19 by:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

I've tested the module build with the 5.19 kernel myself.

Comment: I updated with a command to remove old source directory.

Comment: That worked fine - thanks very much for all your help.